# PowerPoint content add-in is displayed as an image in the present mode

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

We created a simple PowerPoint [content add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins). As the documentation says, content add-ins should work in the Office 2013 and newer:

> Content add-ins are supported in Excel and PowerPoint in Office 2013 version and later. If you open an add-in in a version of Office that doesn’t support Office web add-ins, the add-in will be displayed as an image.

It works as expected for most of our clients but for some of them it doesn't work in a strange way:

- when PowerPoint is in the edit mode, all is ok, the content add-in is rendered and it is interactive
- after PowerPoint is switched to the present mode, only a non-interactive screenshot/image of that content (previously displayed in the edit mode) is rendered and users are not able to make any interaction

Even the official Microsoft [Web Viewer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104295828) content add-in on that particular computer doesn't work - all web pages are displayed as screenshots in the present mode.

Any ideas why it works fine on most of the computers and on some doesn't?

SW versions installed on that "problematic" computer:

```
PowerPoint 2013 (15.0.5093.100)
Windows: Windows 10 Home (1803, build 17134.523)
Internet Explorer 11: 11.523.17134.0
```